# ActiveRecord SQL Query

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord

I have a table in rails 'restaurants' and the corresponding model is 'Restaurant' the schema is code:"postalcode", "name", "address", "chairs:Number of chairs restaurant has as an integer".

I am looking to create a query to find the restaurant with the most chairs by code and then also the name of the place with the most chairs in each code.

I am not quite sure how this would go in activerecord. I created the below query that grabs all of the restaurants and displays their postal code along with the sum of all of the chairs in that code. I am looking for a way to add on to this so that I can also get the name of the restaurant with the most chairs in that code and also that number of chairs.

```
Restaurant.all.group(:code).sum(:chairs)
```

Comment: Is postal code unique per restaurant or a common attribute for many restaurants? If the latter then I think the query you wrote returns the sum of all chairs of all restaurants in a certain postal code.

Comment: Postal code is a common attribute, so many restaurants can be in the same postal code. The query I wrote returns the total number of chairs for each postal code. I am looking for a way to return the restaurant within that postal code with the mode chairs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Restaurant.select("name").group(:code).max(:chairs)
```

This should return the restaurant with mode chairs in each code
I don't think you can have one query to do both things at once.

Comment: irb(main):041:0> Restaurant.select(:name).group(:code).max(:chairs)
  Restaurant Load (3.5ms)  SELECT "restaurants"."name" FROM "restaurants" GROUP BY "restaurants"."code"
PG::GroupingError: ERROR:  column "restaurants.name" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function